# How to reorder list of posts (i.e., new query) based on user input with Flask

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I am building a website in Flask and want to enable the user to sort the main list of posts how he or she chooses to. By default, posts are sorted by their "expiry date" in ascending order. However, some users may want to sort alphabetically, by author name, date posted, etc.

Some sources have suggested I build a string based on user input; however, this doesn't seem like the most effective way to do this (perhaps it is!)

Here's what my code looks like:

```
@index.route("/")
@index.route("/home")
def home():
    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
    experiences = 
Exp.query.order_by(Exp.date_expiry.asc()).paginate(page=page, per_page=5)
    return render_template('home.html', experiences=experiences)
```

I think I need to pass in some sort of variable into my home route, and then uniquely generate my query based off of that, I'm just not sure exactly what the best practice is. Also, I'm not sure how to create a menu for this sort of thing in Flask, though I did some stuff searching around.

Comment: I'm not sure if the question is Flask-related (does OP want to perform the sort in Python on the server, or in JavaScript in HTML, or in SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert your query into a list of dictionaries and then sort the entries according to one or more of the dictionary values using the **operator** module’s **itemgetter** function.

Suppose you have the following list:

```
posts_list = [
     {'post_id':100, 'author_name': 'John', 'date_posted':'2019-02-14', 'expiry_date':'2019-09-20'},
     {'post_id':101, 'author_name': 'Bob', 'date_posted':'2019-03-15', 'expiry_date':'2019-04-25'},
     {'post_id':102, 'author_name': 'Alice', 'date_posted':'2019-01-16', 'expiry_date':'2019-07-24'},
     {'post_id':103, 'author_name': 'Eric', 'date_posted':'2019-04-14', 'expiry_date':'2019-05-20'}
]
```

It is quite easy to output these rows ordered by any of the fields common to all of the dictionaries.

Example:

```
from operator import itemgetter

list_by_author_name = sorted(posts_list, key=itemgetter('author_name'))
list_by_date_posted = sorted(posts_list, key=itemgetter('date_posted'))
list_by_expiry_date = sorted(posts_list, key=itemgetter('expiry_date'))

print(list_by_author_name)
print(list_by_date_posted)
print(list_by_expiry_date)
```

which produces the following result:

```
[
{'post_id': 102, 'author_name': 'Alice', 'date_posted': '2019-01-16', 'expiry_date': '2019-07-24'}, 
{'post_id': 101, 'author_name': 'Bob', 'date_posted': '2019-03-15', 'expiry_date': '2019-04-25'}, 
{'post_id': 103, 'author_name': 'Eric', 'date_posted': '2019-04-14', 'expiry_date': '2019-05-20'}, 
{'post_id': 100, 'author_name': 'John', 'date_posted': '2019-02-14', 'expiry_date': '2019-09-20'}
]

[
{'post_id': 102, 'author_name': 'Alice', 'date_posted': '2019-01-16', 'expiry_date': '2019-07-24'}, 
{'post_id': 100, 'author_name': 'John', 'date_posted': '2019-02-14', 'expiry_date': '2019-09-20'}, 
{'post_id': 101, 'author_name': 'Bob', 'date_posted': '2019-03-15', 'expiry_date': '2019-04-25'}, 
{'post_id': 103, 'author_name': 'Eric', 'date_posted': '2019-04-14', 'expiry_date': '2019-05-20'}
]

[
{'post_id': 101, 'author_name': 'Bob', 'date_posted': '2019-03-15', 'expiry_date': '2019-04-25'}, 
{'post_id': 103, 'author_name': 'Eric', 'date_posted': '2019-04-14', 'expiry_date': '2019-05-20'}, 
{'post_id': 102, 'author_name': 'Alice', 'date_posted': '2019-01-16', 'expiry_date': '2019-07-24'}, 
{'post_id': 100, 'author_name': 'John', 'date_posted': '2019-02-14', 'expiry_date': '2019-09-20'}
]
```